# Turning a list of coordinates into a set of list/grid references

Tags: python

I have a list which will get the top left section of a grid that is 2n+1 size.

```
n = 1
section = [[x, y] for x in range (n+1) for y in range (n+1)]
```

which looks like: `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]` and will get the coordinates of the top left hand corner of the 3x3(2n+1) grid, e.g:

`[[1, 2, 3],
  [4, 0, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]]`

I can then get every single quarter section of the grid by editing the values of the coords in this list:

```
for coOrd in topRight:
    coOrd[1] += n
for coOrd in botLeft:
    coOrd[0] += n
for coOrd in botRight:
    coOrd[0] += n
    coOrd[1] += n
```

I need to somehow individualise every second list element from

```
[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]... -> [0][0], [0][1], [1][0]
```

so that I can use it to reference a grid list which has the values for the entire grid, which will look something like this: `gridList[0][0], gridList[0][1]`

I would prefer to be able to get each section via a for loop that will go through each coordinate in topLeft, topRight etc, and apply these to the gridList.

```
gridTL = [gridList[0][0], gridList[0][1], gridList[1][0], gridList[1][1]]
gridTR = [gridList[0][1], gridList[0][2], gridList[1][1], gridList[1][2]]
gridBL = [gridList[1][0], gridList[1][1], gridList[2][0], gridList[2][1]]
gridBR = [gridList[1][1], gridList[1][2], gridList[2][1], gridList[2][2]]
```

Hopefully I have explained well enough for you to understand, If I haven't sorry, please do ask more and I will try my best to explain.

Essentially it boils  down to: I need to split a (3x3) grid into 4 sections, I have come up with a loop to grab the coordinates, I am struggling to implement these coordinates to be able to grab values from the grid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a helper function:

```
def gL(gridList, values): 
    return gridlist[values[0]][values[1]]
```

Then, your

```
gridTL = map(lambda m: gl(gridList, m), section)
```

Where, `section` is any of the sections you want ...

Note:

`map` isnt considered very Pythonic. You can consider using list comprehensions for similar things. Something like this :

```
gridTL = [gridlist[m[0]][m[1]]for m in section]
```

Comment: Thanks man, you are a god! I was trying to work it out using a list comprehension but was getting error after error after error.